# Hosting Web API and another custom service in a .NET Core Console application

Tags: c#, .net-core

I premise that I'm new to .NET Core and usually in Full Framework I used TopShelf to use console app as service.

Now I've successfully created my .NET Core application that serves WebApi, but I need to attach another service I wrote (it's an IBMMQ service that receives messages and dispatches them back).

My current program.cs is

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlClientFactory.Instance);
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

            var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                // .UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();

        }
    }
```

and here's my startup

```
 class Startup
    {
        private readonly Container container = new Container();

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            IntegrateSimpleInjector(services);

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSimpleInjector(container);

            services.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true)
                .UseSimpleInjector(container);
        }

        private void IntegrateSimpleInjector(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            container.Options.DependencyInjectionBehavior =
                new SerilogContextualLoggerInjectionBehavior(container.Options);

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(
                new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(container));

            services.EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring(container);

            services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            InitializeContainer(app);

            DataConnection.DefaultSettings = new Linq2DbSettings();
            LinqToDB.Common.Configuration.Linq.AllowMultipleQuery = true;

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpointRouteBuilder => endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllers());
            container.RegisterMvcControllers(app);
            container.Verify();


        }

        private void InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
          //register container

        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can add my service's startup here?

Thanks

Comment: The question is a bit confusing - in .NET Core, even web apps are console apps that just start the proper service. Long-running tasks, timed jobs etc, are implemented as [IHostedService/BackgroudService implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio). If that's what you want, you need to create a class that inherits from BackgroundService and register it with `AddHostedService`

Comment: Or are you asking how to host your entire application as a service on Windows or Linux? That's the job of the [worker service](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/dotnetNewWorkerWindowsServicesOrLinuxSystemdServicesInNETCore.aspx). The background work is still performed by BackgroundService classes but the app itself is hosted either as a Windows Service or a Systemd worker

Comment: Hello @PanagiotisKanavos, your first comment should do the trick, I'm testing it, in that case, after my test, I comment you here, if you post it as answer I vote it